# how to copy child or tag in xml twig by xpath?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I am new to xml twig.. I need copy from xpath to xpath, how can i do it? I was tried some method but it can't work properly, so please any one help.. how can i copy tag from xpath  to xpath in xml file... how can i get this option xml::twig...

my input:

```
<xml>
<front>
 <sample>
<a>link <bo>ale</bo></a>
</sample>
</front>
<body>
<p>some text</p>
</body>
</xml>
```

I need copy tag by xpath...

```
from : //front/sample/ 
to : //body/
```

I need output as:

```
<xml>
    <front>
     <sample>

    </sample>
    </front>
    <body>
    <a>link <bo>ale</bo></a>
    <p>some text</p>
    </body>
    </xml>
```

I try:

```
use XML::Twig:

 my $Tag_move = XML::Twig->new(
                               twig_handlers =>{
                                        'xml' => \&Tag_Alt,
                               },
                               pretty_print => 'indented',
);
$Tag_move->parsefile(input.xml);
$Tag_move->print;

sub Tag_Alt{
        my ($Tag_move, $tagm) = @_;
             my @c = $tagm->findnodes('//front/sample/');   
             my $chi = $tagm->copy_children(@c);
             $chi->paste('first_child', $tagm->findnodes('//body/'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be having problems with scalars vs arrays. Maybe a consequence of using jQuery in a previous life? ;--)

In any case, your sub would work if you write this:

```
sub Tag_Alt{
  my ($Tag_move, $tagm) = @_;
  my @c = $tagm->findnodes('//front/sample/');   
  my @children= map { $_->cut_children } @c;
  foreach my $child (@children) {
    $child->paste('first_child', ($tagm->findnodes('//body/'))[0]); 
  }     
}
```

I would write this differently though:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my @samples;

my $Tag_move = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers =>{ # cut and store the everything within sample
                      sample => sub { push @samples, $_->cut_children; },
                      # paste the samples within the body
                      body   => sub { foreach my $sample (@samples) 
                                        { $sample->paste( first_child => $_); }
                                    },
                    },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
    empty_tags => 'expand',   # otherwise the empty sample is output as <sample/>
);
$Tag_move->parsefile( "input.xml")
        ->print;
```

BTW, do yourself a favour, and use `strict` and `warnings`. This will catch a lot of the mistakes you make. You will get errors instead of allowing unknown variables to be created silently.

Comment: another one doubt, how to read <DOCTYPE> tag how can save another file that tag because i read some file root tag base but i can't read <DTD> tag, so please help this question?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Post a question with code and sample input/output, you will have a better chance at an answer.

Comment: k I will post next question with samples  @mirod

Comment: I post my question please help this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257891/how-to-read-and-change-doctype-tag-and-xml-version-1-0-in-xml-twig