# Perl data structure to xml

Tags: perl

I have got perl data something like below:

```
$data = {
   id => 1,
   name => "A",
   users  => [ { id => 1, name => "u1" }, { id => 2, name => "u2" } ],
   groups => [ { id => 1, name => "g1" } ]
};
```

I would like to convert this into an xml something like below:

```
<map>
  <item id="1" name="A">
     <users>
        <user id="1" name="u1"/>
        <user id="2" name="u2"/> 
     </users>
     <groups>
        <group id="1" name="g1"/>
     </groups>         
  </item>
</map>
```

I could do that manually creating each line explicitly. However I am looking for any CPAN Module base solution.

I tried XML::Twig but didn't go anywhere. I have used XML::Simple in the past for such thing but this time wanted to try something else as XML::Simple has been getting bad reviews.

Comment: How did you create this data structure in the first place? It's far from ideal for creating XML data, and looks like something that `XML::Simple` would create. For instance, there's no way of knowing the names of the elements inside `groups` and `users`. And where do the names `map` and `item` come from?

Comment: I think you'll get something like that from parsing JSON - JSON has arrays in it, where XML doesn't.

Comment: @Sobrique: But `XML::Simple` creates stuff like that :)

Comment: Another reason not to like `XML::Simple` then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, wise choice. [`XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm) ... isn't. It's *for* simple XML.

As noted in the comments though - your data is a little ambiguous - specifically, how do you tell what the elements should be called within 'groups' or 'users'.

This looks like you might have parsed some JSON. (Indeed, you can turn it straight back into JSON:

```
print to_json ( $data, { pretty => 1 } );
```

The core problem is - where JSON supports arrays, XML does not. So there's really very little you could do that will *directly* turn your data structure into XML.

However if you don't mind doing a bit of work yourself:

Here's how you assemble some XML using [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.48/Twig.pm)

[Assembling XML in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009370/assembling-xml-in-perl/29009769#29009769)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( 'pretty_print' => 'indented' );
$twig->set_root( 
    XML::Twig::Elt->new(
        'map',
    )
);
my $item = $twig->root->insert_new_elt('item', { 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'A' } );
my $users = $item ->insert_new_elt( 'users' );
   $users -> insert_new_elt ( 'user', { 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'u1' } );
   $users -> insert_new_elt ( 'user', { 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'u2' } );

my $groups = $item -> insert_new_elt ('last_child', 'groups');
   $groups -> insert_new_elt ( 'group', { 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'g1' } );

$twig->set_xml_version("1.0");
$twig->set_encoding('utf-8');

$twig->print;
```

Which prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<map>
  <item id="1" name="A">
    <users>
      <user id="2" name="u2"/>
      <user id="1" name="u1"/>
    </users>
    <groups>
      <group id="1" name="g1"/>
    </groups>
  </item>
</map>
```

Iterating your data structure is left as an exercise for the reader.

As Borodin correctly notes - you have no way to infer `map` `item` `group` or `user` from your data structure. The latter two you can *perhaps* infer based on plurals, but given your data set, the best I can come up with is something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $data = {
    id    => 1,
    name  => "A",
    users => [ { id => 1, name => "u1" }, { id => 2, name => "u2" } ],
    groups => [ { id => 1, name => "g1" } ]
};


my $twig = XML::Twig->new( 'pretty_print' => 'indented' );
$twig->set_root( XML::Twig::Elt->new( 'map', ) );

my $item = $twig->root->insert_new_elt('item');
foreach my $key ( keys %$data ) {
    if ( not ref $data->{$key} ) {
        $item->set_att( $key, $data->{$key} );
        next;
    }
    if ( ref( $data->{$key} ) eq "ARRAY" ) {
        my $fakearray = $item->insert_new_elt($key);
        foreach my $element ( @{ $data->{$key} } ) {
            my $name = $key;
               $name =~ s/s$//g;
            $fakearray->insert_new_elt( $name, $element );
        }
        next;
    }
    if ( ref ( $data -> {$key} ) eq "HASH" ) { 
        $item -> insert_new_elt( $key, $data -> {$key} );
        next;
    }
}

$twig->set_xml_version("1.0");
$twig->set_encoding('utf-8');

$twig->print;
```

This isn't ideal because - `map` is hardcoded, as is `item`. And I take the very simplistic approach of assuming the array has an `s` on the end, to pluralise it.

Comment: That would create the correct XML, sure, but I think the OP is looking for a *generic* way of converting a Perl data structure to XML. You may as well just type in the XML instead of typing code to create it.

Comment: I'd read it as a fairly large data structure, which'd need to be iterated to make some XML, rather than typing it all by hand. If it's just smooshing ... something from JSON (maybe?) into XML, that's altogether more complicated.

Comment: Then we agree. But your code doesn't make any use of the OP's data structure. As I commented above, there's no way to get the tag names `map`, `item`, `user` or `group`.

Comment: Hmm, yes. You have to make certain assumptions. 'user' and 'group' you can perhaps fudge because of plurals, but ...

Comment: Thanks Sobrique for your solution, much appreciated.

Comment: It's not particularly complete, but hopefully it gives you a suitable start point?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it similarly to Sobrique's method but with less hardcoded strings, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $data = {
    id => 1,
    name => "A",
    users  => [ { id => 1, name => "u1" }, { id => 2, name => "u2" } ],
    groups => [ { id => 1, name => "g1" } ]
};

sub array_to_elts {
    my ( $root, $name, $arrayref ) = @_;
    map { $root->insert_new_elt($name, $_) } @{ $arrayref };
}

my $twig  = XML::Twig
    ->new()
    ->set_xml_version("1.0")
    ->set_encoding('utf-8');

my $map = XML::Twig::Elt->new('map');
$twig->set_root($map);

my $item  = $map->insert_new_elt(
    'item',
    { id => $data->{'id'}, name => $data->{'name'} },
);

my $lines = $item->insert_new_elt('groups');
my $links = $item->insert_new_elt('users' );

array_to_elts($lines, 'group', $data->{'groups'});
array_to_elts($links, 'user',  $data->{'users' });

$twig->set_pretty_print('indented');
$twig->print;
```

You could go to extreme lengths to reduce the hardcoded vals and base more off the raw data, but it quickly gets harder to read..

Comment: Thanks for your solution, David, as always.

Comment: Is it true that `insert_new_elt` applied on an array reverts the order, i.e.: `insert_new_elt` inserts the new element before the last one?

Answer (score 1):

"Generic" way using [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML). You might need to add new code to the "else" part to handle other types of structures.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::LibXML;

my $data = {
            id     => 1,
            name   => "A",
            users  => [ { id => 1, name => "u1" },
                        { id => 2, name => "u2" } ],
            groups => [ { id => 1, name => "g1" } ],
           };

sub to_xml {
    my ($data, $xml) = @_;
    for my $entry (keys %$data) {
        my $ref = ref $data->{$entry};
        if (not $ref) {
            $xml->setAttribute($entry, $data->{$entry});

        } elsif ('ARRAY' eq $ref) {
            (my $name = $entry) =~ s/s$// or die "Can't guess the element name.\n";
            my $list = $xml->addNewChild(q(), $entry);
            for my $inner (@{ $data->{$entry} }) {
                to_xml($inner, $list->addNewChild(q(), $name));
            }

        } else {
            die "Unhandled structure $ref.\n";
        }
    }
}

my $xml = 'XML::LibXML::Document'->createDocument;
my $root = $xml->createElement('map');
$xml->setDocumentElement($root);
for my $entry ($data) {
    my $item = $root->addNewChild(q(), 'item');
    to_xml($entry, $item);
}

print $xml;
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, Choroba. I must say this looks hardcore.

Comment: @MohammadSajidAnwar: XML is hardcore :-)

Comment: Maybe edit your answer to include where `addNewChild` is documented; I could not find it in neither: XML::LibXML, nor XML::LibXML::Document.

Comment: `addNewChild` is documented in [XML::LibXML::Node](https://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML::Node).