# perl XML handling module by default

Tags: xml, perl

Can i use default perl (say Strawberry perl 5.20 v) to build xml and populate its content with mine data? Or it is better to use modules from cpan like libXML or SimpleXML ? Are any useful modules default by installation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recommendation question, so typically that's offtopic. However I will draw your attention to this from `XML::Simple`.

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces. In particular, XML::LibXML is highly recommended.

Depending on the task, different libraries are 'good'. `XML::LibXML` or `XML::Twig` are solid choices. `XML::Simple` isn't - it's prone to making bad code.

Above all though - you should DEFINITELY use a parser, because whilst XML looks a bit like plain text, it isn't - there are some actually quite strict rules about what is - and isn't - OK in XML, and there are some semantically identical snippets of XML that have completely different formatting.

This question is my attempt at assembling XML with `XML::Twig`.

[Assembling XML in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009370/assembling-xml-in-perl)

You will probably have to install either of these modules. But don't worry. Installing modules is a Good Thing, and one of the reasons why Perl is so good.

Answer (score 2):

[***Strawberry Perl***](http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html) is bundled with many useful prebuilt modules, including the excellent [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) and [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig)

I recommend [`XML::Writer`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Writer) for creating XML documents from scratch, but unfortunately it isn't on the list of bundled modules. However [`App::cpanminus`](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus) is there, which means you can add to your collection of utilities with

```
cpanm XML::Writer
```

from the command line

Comment: Having used Activestate extensively, it's useful to know Strawberry ships with those.