# How to partition an inconsistent XML - Perl

Tags: xml, perl, xml-simple

Say how do you parse through this particular XML using perl

A little background: I'm writing a perl script where I separate the XML(datamod) into two XML files.

#### Example: Existing XML

```xml
<Root>
 <Top>
  <Module name="ALU">
   <input name="po_ctrl"/>
   <bidirection name="add"/>
  </Module>
  <Module name="Po_ctrl">
   <input name="ctrl"/>
   <output name="ctrlbus"/>
   <bidirection name="add"/>
  </Module>
  <input name="add"/>
  <input name="clk"/>
  <input name="da_in"/>
  <output name="da_out"/>
  <bidirection name="ctrl"/>
 </Root>
</Top>
```

Below is the perl snippet written

```xml
 open(IN_FILE, "<datamod.xml") or die "Cant open input file";
 open(TM1_FILE, ">tm1.xml") or die "Cant Open tm1.xml";
 open(TM2_FILE, ">tm2.xml") or die "Cant Open tm2.xml"; 
 my $chk = 0;
 while(my $line = <IN_FILE>){
 $line =~ s/^\s+//;
 @xwords = split(" ",$line);
 if($xwords[0] ne "<Module" and $xwords[0] ne "</Module>"  and $chk ==0) {
   print TM1_FILE $line;
  }  
  else {
   print TM2_FILE $line;
   $chk = 1;
  }   
 if($xwords[0] eq "</Module>" and $chk == 1) {
  $chk = 0;
 }  
}
close TM1_FILE;
close TM2_FILE;
```

***Expected output into two temp files***

***Temp file 1:***

```
   <Root>
      <Top>
       <input name="add"/>
       <input name="clk"/>
       <input name="da_in"/>
       <output name="da_out"/>
       <bidirection name="ctrl"/>
      </Top>
    </Root>
```

***Temp File 2***

```
<Root>
 <Top>
  <Module name="ALU">
   <input name="po_ctrl"/>
   <bidirection name="add"/>
  </Module>
  <Module name="Po_ctrl">
   <input name="ctrl"/>
   <output name="ctrlbus"/>
   <bidirection name="add"/>
  </Module>
</Root>
</Top>
```

**NOTE:** I'm using the [`XML::Simple`](http://metacpan.org/module/XML::Simple) module because the Perl script is written in it and it's tedious to convert to any other XML module.

Any help is appreciated, kindly post the rewritten snippet!

Comment: Your existing XML isn't valid.

Comment: @Sobrique I have edited the question again!

Comment: Thought you said you were using XML::Simple?

Comment: @Sobrique That's right! You can my answer in _Answers_ section

Comment: No, that isn't. It is some dirty regular expression hackery,  it isn't using a parser.

Comment: @Sobrique let me re-check it again!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not included any code, or how your data is at the moment, I'm going to suggest this simple hack. Just add it as text before you parse the XML.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $xml = <your xml here>;
$xml = "<Root>\n" . $xml . "</Root>\n";
```

Comment: there are few complications in my code and I'm trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

[Don't use regular expressions for XML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) XML is a recursive data structure, and whilst you can technically do recursion with regex, it leads to dirty code. So practically you end up with some *very* selective hackery that'll one day mysteriously break, because a perfectly valid XML change doesn't fit your regex any more.

Also: [Don't use XML::Simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged) for much the same reason. (Despite you saying you are using it in your question, there is no sign of your doing so in the code you have posted).

With a proper parser what you are trying to do becomes very simple. I like `XML::Twig`, `XML::LibXML` is probably better, but has a steeper learning curve. Either are less prone to future misery and shoddy code.

What you're trying to do seems to be to split XML, and put `modules` in one, and "everything else" in another. This is done in `XML::Twig` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

#parse your input
my $twig = XML::Twig->new->parsefile( 'datamod.xml' ); 

#create a new 'modules' document. 
my $modules = XML::Twig->new;
#create a root
$modules->set_root( XML::Twig::Elt->new('Root') );
#create a "Top" element. (You can compound this if you want)
my $top = $modules->root->insert_new_elt('Top');
#set output format (note - this can break in specific edge cases - your XML
#doesn't seem to be one of those). 
$modules->set_pretty_print('indented_a');

#find all the "<Module>" elements. 
foreach my $module ( $twig->findnodes('//Module') ) {
    #cut from old doc
    $module->cut;
    #paste into new. last_child ensures same ordering.
    $module->paste( 'last_child', $top );
}

#print the output to a file.  
open ( my $output, '>', 'tm1.xml' ) or warn $!; 
print {$output} $twig -> sprint; 
close ( $output ); 

open ( my $second_output, '>', 'tm2.xml' ) or warn $!;
print {$second_output} $modules -> sprint; 
close ( $second_output );
```

Note - there's a bit more on assembling a new XML document here: [Assembling XML in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009370/assembling-xml-in-perl/29009769#29009769)

You may want to consider setting encoding and versions.