# How to ease later parse on NetApp 7-Mode?

Tags: netapp

I would like to parse and extract useful information from several Netapp commands output such as `sysconfig`, `uptime` and so on.

I had already done it on Netapp Clustered Mode (C-Mode) because `set` command made my life much easier with this kind of sentences:

- Custom delimiter character:

  ```
  set -showseparator '!';
  ```
- Unlimited terminal lenght.

  ```
  set -rows 0;
  ```
- Show all fields

  ```
  set -showallfields true;
  ```

However, `set` command does not exist in Netapp 7-Mode.
¿Does any one know something similar to modify the terminal length, units, field separator?

This is the version I have in hands:

```
3250-01> version
NetApp Release 8.1.2P4 7-Mode: Fri Apr 26 19:57:25 PDT 2013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no similar functionality in 7-mode. You have to parse the output. It's not too bad for some commands (like `df` or `version`) but others have formatting, and it gets very messy (like `aggr show_space` and `vol status`)

The closest you get is to make API calls and parse resultant XML. That's a bit more complicated, but I've got some [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009370/assembling-xml-in-perl/29009769#29009769) of how it might work.